# WebView won't execute site commands

Tags: java, android, webview

I have a WebView that loads this [WebSite](https://ib.rendimento.com.br)

If you try to put an identification and click out of the box, it shows a little loading and tells if the identification is correct it shows a virtual keyboard within the site, not a device keyboard, if its incorrect it shows a error message, like this

[Site showing error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bmsT.png)

However, if i put the same website on my WebView, it loads the site perfectly, but it won't execute these commands, if i put any identification and click out it doesn't shows the loading, it won't do anything.

Funny part is, if i do the same WebView in Xcode for iPhone, it does everything normally, even the commands, it checks for the identification, etc...

**What i've tried**

Turning on/off:

```
Javascript
Plugins(even deprecated)
```

My code:

```
package com.example.viskee.webview;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    WebView wbAba = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wbAba);
    wbAba.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    wbAba.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wbAba.loadUrl("https://ib.rendimento.com.br");

    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

If i use

```
wbAba.setChromeClient(new ChromeClient);
```

it works fine, however i don't want to use ChromeClient because it adds an address bar, etc... I want my WebView to be FullScreen, show only the website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, all i had to do was:

```
wbAba.getSettings().setDomStorageEnable(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you try this:

```
WebView wbAba = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wbAba);
wbAba.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

wbAba.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
wbAba.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);

wbAba.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
wbAba.loadUrl("https://ib.rendimento.com.br");
```

and one final thing, don't forget to set internet permission on manifest.xml file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

Let me know, if this doesn't work.

Comment: Hello Dharma, thank you for your reply. I already got a solution, i had to implement this wbAba.getSettings().setDomStorageEnable(true);

Comment: Ok Viskee, No problem.